# How to move/position Modal dynamically with div id?

Tags: javascript, html, css

i have used several steps out there like
absolute - relative position
but nothing works for me
and also div have to highlighted
by backdroping remaining elements

**HTML**

```
<!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade in" id="myModal" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">

            <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">

                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="title1"></h4>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default prevBtn">Previous</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default skipBtn" data-dismiss="modal">Skip</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default nextBtn">Next</button>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="modal-arrow"></div>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.modal-dialog {
    position: absolute;
    top: 400px;
    right: 100px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 10040;
    overflow: auto;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
.relative1{
   position:relative;
}

.btn-default {
    color: black;
}


.modal,
.modal-backdrop {
    position: absolute !important;
}

.modal-backdrop.fade {
    opacity: 0;
}




.modal-backdrop.show {
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

called modal using JS

here the modal only displays at center of the screen
it have to be adjacent to the div.

Answer (score 0):

With css, add/change this

```
#myModal .modal-dialog {
  top: 50px;
  right: 800px;
}
```

or with Javascript, add this somewhere below the modal

```
var myModal = document.querySelector("#myModal .modal-dialog");
myModal.style.top = "50px";
myModal.style.right = "80px";
```